# Why doesn't the "Our security auditor is an idiot" question appear in the list of most upvoted questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Our security auditor is an idiot. How do I give him the information he wants?](https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants)

[image]

And yes, I am on the first page. I reproduced this in Chrome 38 and IE 11. The "votes" tab does not appear when unauthenticated, so I cannot check it as an anomymous user.

Comment: A [data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/246799/real-top-questions) can give you the list including locked questions, if you're interested. It won't include deleted ones, though. At least, I don't think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is locked and retained for *historical significance* - from the close reason

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

Note the emphasis - it's not really topical.  That's the reason why it's hidden so this is not a bug, it is by design.

Comment: Ah, so that's why. Any reason why you gave the same answer twice?

Comment: That could be a bug or it could be a browser plugin incompatibility. I posted the answer then left this page then came back via the browser back button then added some text.